# Does python package pandasql support create table SQL command?

Tags: python, pandasql

I want to create table using pandasql library in python. Is it supported? as I am getting error as follows:

```
p = pandasql.sqldf('CREATE TABLE Persons (trial TEXT,case TEXT);')
```

**The error message is:**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  in 
    p = pandasql.sqldf('CREATE TABLE Persons (trial TEXT,case TEXT);')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandasql\sqldf.py", line 156, in sqldf
    return PandaSQL(db_uri)(query, env)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandasql\sqldf.py", line 63, in **call**
    raise PandaSQLException(ex)
pandasql.sqldf.PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "case": syntax error
[SQL: CREATE TABLE Persons (trial TEXT,case TEXT);]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

Answer (score 0):

To create, append to, or overwrite a table with the data in a DataFrame, you can use [`DataFrame.to_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html#pandas-dataframe-to-sql):

> Write records stored in a DataFrame to a SQL database.
>
> Databases supported by SQLAlchemy [[1]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html#r689dfd12abe5-1) are supported. Tables can be newly created, appended to, or overwritten.

To create new tables separately or before inserting data from the DataFrame, use [SQLAlchemy queries](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#advanced-sqlalchemy-queries) directly:

> If you have an SQLAlchemy description of your database you can express
>   where conditions using SQLAlchemy expressions
>
> ```
> In [539]: metadata = sa.MetaData()
>
> In [540]: data_table = sa.Table('data', metadata,
>    .....:                       sa.Column('index', sa.Integer),
>    .....:                       sa.Column('Date', sa.DateTime),
>    .....:                       sa.Column('Col_1', sa.String),
>    .....:                       sa.Column('Col_2', sa.Float),
>    .....:                       sa.Column('Col_3', sa.Boolean),
>    .....:                       )
>    .....: 
>
> In [541]: pd.read_sql(sa.select([data_table]).where(data_table.c.Col_3 is True), engine)
> Out[541]: 
> Empty DataFrame
> Columns: [index, Date, Col_1, Col_2, Col_3]
> Index: []
> ```